# Instance VM Creation

Tags: fiware-orion, filab

I was trying to launch a instance VM to do some test. I selected the image orion-psb-image-R4, but when I launch the instance, an error appears:

```
(Status:ERROR Power State:No State), is impossible to associate an a Public IP (Error: undefined. Cause: 400 Error info).
```

I created my key pair, my public IP and my security group (I'm using the default security group, but I created two new rules to use ports 1026 and 22), entered image description, then trying to launch a instance VM to do some tests.

Comment: Why did you revert all the improvements I made to your post (esp. those related to the language)? Did I get something wrong?

Comment: sorry, please do it again, i'm newer on this foro!

Answer (score 0):

Taking into accoun the comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27565063/orion-context-broker-does-not-start-at-fiware-lab), this is an specific question related with the FIWARE Lab cloud infrastructure, rather than with Orion Context Broker itself, and there are better channels to deal with it. Please send an email to fiware-lab-help@lists.fi-ware.org in order that we can make a following or this issue and you can know when it was resolved.

Please take into account that the more details (region, id of the instance, image, etc.) you give us as the more help us to resolve the problem